# How to install older version of firefox in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: firefox, browser

I am using firefox 21 but I faced more problems with firefox like many times hang or slow working the browser so I want to install older version means firefox 20 after remove firefox 21 version.
Please tell me the procedure of above work.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a 32 bit system download: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/20.0.1/linux-i686/en-US/firefox-20.0.1.tar.bz2

If you have a 64 bit system download:
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/20.0.1/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-20.0.1.tar.bz2

If you don't know how to install the files see:
[How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)